# How to read digits into array till the end of line?

Tags: c++

How to make a program that read digits form text file into array while there is numbers in current line then i want to print that line on screen and repeat everything while there is lines. How to do this? Once i heard about dynamic arrays maybe i should use them?

```
int k = 0;
int paz[14];
int sk;
file >> n;  // n - number of lines
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    while ( file >> sk )
    {

            paz[k] = sk;
            cout << paz[k] << " ";
            k++;


    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Text file:
In each line can be form 0 to 10 numbers. First line shows number of lines and lines separated with comma

```
2,
9 5 10 7 8 9 7 12 7 17,
0 1 7 0 14 4 ,
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use dynamic arrays. They are called vectors. They are very easy to use and a very good replacement for arrays.

The code with vector, would look like this:

```
#include <vector>
int k = 0;
vector<int> paz;
int sk;
file >> n;  // n - number of lines
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    while ( file >> sk )
    {

            paz.push_back(sk);
            cout << paz[k] << " ";
            k++;


    }
    cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, code is working but how to limit this vector size to 14?

Comment: You can reserve the space for the vector at the beginning by doing paz.reserve(14); This means it will have space for 14 elements. Of course if you will want to put more elements in it it will just resize. Documentation available here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/